# Can I destructure an array in a Javascript arrow function?

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions, destructuring

Does any version of Javascript support destructuring of arrays in arrow functions? E.g.

```
const items = [ [1, 2], [3, 4] ];
const sums = items.map( [a, b] => a + b );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can, but you have to surround the parameter in parentheses:

```js
const items = [ [1, 2], [3, 4] ];
const sums = items.map(([a, b]) => a + b );
console.log(sums);
```